# Proof-making for "A Set is a Subset of Itself" / Law of Identity.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Recently I've been trying to figure out a proof regarding set theory, for the following theorem:

"A set is a subset of itself" or $∀x:S ⊆ S$, or:

$∀x:  (x∈S ⟹    x∈S)$

[ProofWiki states](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_is_Subset_of_Itself) that such a problem can be solved with the law of identity, but I do not understand how that works, as such a law is only used with conjunctions and disjunctions, and not conditional statements. I figure I could do something using the definition of a subset but I do not know where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, but then why is the law of identity according to propositional logic as follows?

Comment: Oops, pressed enter too early. Why is it: P V F ≡ P, P Λ T ≡ P?

Comment: That's a different principle, which someone else happens to  call by the same name. But when proofWiki says "Law of identity", it means something else. ProofWiki calls $p\lor F = p$ by the name [Disjunction with contradiction](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Disjunction_with_Contradiction) and $p\land T = p$ by the name [Conjunction with tautology](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjunction_with_Tautology).

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The names for these things aren't standard. Like almost everything else about language and terminology, different people call things by different names. The important thing, when reading something written by person $X$, is to find out what person $X$ means. So when you see in ProofWiki that it says that something follows by the "Law of Identity", and that doesn't make sense for the thing _you_ think is the Law of Identity, you just need to follow the wiki link to the page that explains what _pProofWiki_ means by "Law of Identity".

Answer (score 4):

The usual axioms of first-order logic with *equality* are (the *generalization* of) :

> $x = x$;
>
> $x = y \to (\alpha \to \alpha')$, where $α$ is atomic and $α'$  is obtained from $α$ by replacing $x$ in zero or more (but not necessarily all) places by $y$

[see Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA112) (2nd ed - 2001), page 112].

In *set theory* the atomic formulae are precisely the formulae : $x \in s$.

Thus, applying the second axiom with the formula $x \in s$ as $\alpha$, we get :

> > $x=x \to (x \in s \to x \in s)$.

Then, using the first axiom : $x=x$, we can "detach" : $(x \in s \to x \in s)$ and finally we "generalize" it to conclude with :

> $\forall x (x \in s \to x \in s)$.

---

See also [Application to Equality of Sets of Leibniz's Law](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Leibniz%27s_Law).

Comment: That seems to be a very roundabout way of proving an instance of a _propositional tautology_, especially when ProofWiki's meaning of "law of identity" is not the one you're using.

Answer (score 3):

The "[Law of identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Law_of_Identity)", as given in ProofWiki, is that $$p\implies p$$ for any formula $p$.  Here the formula is $x\in S$, and by the law of identity, $$x\in S \implies x\in S$$ which is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The name "law of identity" is sometimes (and in particular [on ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Law_of_Identity)) used to denote the rule that
$$ P \Rightarrow P $$
is always valid for every formula $P$. That is, anything implies itself.

In your case, if we let $P$ be the formula $x\in S$, we get a proof of
$$ x\in S \Rightarrow x\in S $$
and the rule of generalization (in whichever form it exists in your particular logical system) then allows us to conclude
$$ \forall x (x\in S\Rightarrow x\in S) $$
which is exactly what "$S\subseteq S$" is an abbreviation for.